# Invoking stored procedure from other schema to create tables

Tags: java, mysql, java-stored-procedures

I am working on the web application project developed using java. In my working project,
i have the requirement like i need to create the database dynamically after the user has been registered.I had done that approach.

But, now i want to call one stored procedure that is available in another schema(Master DB).The stored procedures contains tables. Now, i want to call that procedure in dynamically created DB.

I have written the code like following, can anybody help me to know what's wrong in this code,

```
Connection c1 = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASSWORD);
java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt=null;
System.out.println("Invoking the stored procedure from subscription DB........");      
String callSP="{call masterdb.createCorporateDBProc()};";
cstmt= c1.prepareCall(callSP);
cstmt.execute();

java.sql.CallableStatement cstmt=null;
try {
    System.out.println("Invoking the stored procedure from subscription DB........");      
    String callSP="{call subscription.createCorporateDBProc()}";
    cstmt = c1.prepareCall(callSP);
    int r = cstmt.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("SP created"+r);
    System.out.println("SP invoked and executed successfully in corporate DB....");
}  catch(com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    cstmt.close();
    c1.close();
}
```

Comment: Where is the problem? Some exception?

Comment: I didn't get any exception while creating the stored procedure...      Following is the log for your reference                                         new DB url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/flkhlkfh
[artifact:mvn] **** Started ****
[artifact:mvn] Invoking the stored procedure from subscription DB........
[artifact:mvn] SP invoked and executed successfully in corporate DB....
[artifact:mvn] **** Endeded ****

Comment: And what is the problem? Does it execute? Does it work? Does it hang? Please explain where you have a problem.

Comment: Actually, the code block i had written is working to invoke the stored procedure created without any exception and hanging problem.Now, my problem is the stored procedure not executing. Should i want to provide any privilege to access the other schema stored procedures, DDL statements?

Comment: do you mean that java code runs smoothly but masterdb.createCorporateDBProc() has no effect? How do you know that it is not executed? Can you update this prcedure with some log? Is there commit?

Comment: I am returning the value using  `(int r = cstmt.executeUpdate(); System.out.println("SP created"+r);` to check whether the stored procedure is executing or not. I am getting the 0 as returned value.

Comment: show complete source code please, this part is missing in original question

Comment: i had updated the code written for this functionality Mr.Leos

Answer (score 0):

See javadoc for Statement:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeUpdate%28java.lang.String%29

Returns:
    either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

This means that execute for procedure will return 0. Check your database as well, if the call was successful.